# Adding contact Form7 uploaded file link, to customer complete order email detail

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, contact-form-7

I am working on a woocommerce site, I have added a contact form 7 voice recorder plugin, which works on product page,This plugin is working fine and send the dropbox link of the recorded voice in the email of contact form and only works when add to cart is clicked, But i want that link on my complete order email template also,So i can get the link of the dropbox also with all the product details, I dont know from where to start.

[image]

Comment: Hi Rahuldev , Please share the site link.

Comment: Hi, Thankyou For replying   https://artbeatsusa.com/product/blackwhite/